# How can i use COUNTIFS only when there is data present in an adjacent cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

I am trying to get `G19` in sheet `STATISTICS` to only populate with data calculated from the `COUNTIFS` formula shown below when `F19` of sheet `STATISTICS` has data within. If there is no data calculated for `F19`(i.e. an empty cell returned) (separate formula) then `G19` should return a blank.

The `COUNTIFS` formula shown is counting the amount of `L`'s within column `O` on sheet `TRADE LOG` between the dates of `01 Feb 2021` and `28 Feb 2021`.

This is the formula I am currently using in G19 :

`=IF(COUNTIFS('SHARES LOG'!O:O,"L",'SHARES LOG'!B:B,">="&DATE(2021,2,1),'SHARES LOG'!B:B,"<="&DATE(2021,2,28)), COUNTIFS('SHARES LOG'!O:O,"L",'SHARES LOG'!B:B,">="&DATE(2021,2,1),'SHARES LOG'!B:B,"<="&DATE(2021,2,28)),"")`

If anyone could tweak this to make it produce the data as detailed above that would be great.

Comment: `This is the formula I am currently using in G16` - should that be `g19`?

Comment: Just edited, yes it should be

Comment: One other question `If there is no data calculated for F19` how is "no data" defined? blank/zero/"no data"?

Comment: Defined as a blank column. ```=IF(COUNTIFS('SHARES LOG'!O:O,"W",'SHARES LOG'!B:B,">="&DATE(2021,2,1),'SHARES LOG'!B:B,"<="&DATE(2021,2,28)), COUNTIFS('SHARES LOG'!O:O,"W",'SHARES LOG'!B:B,">="&DATE(2021,2,1),'SHARES LOG'!B:B,"<="&DATE(2021,2,28)),"")```    That is the current formula in ```F19```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `F19` returns `""` in the second part if the `IF(...)` then you can't test using `ISBLANK(F19)`, so I would use the following (indented for clarity) for `G19`, basically wrap the original formula inside `IF(TRIM(F19)="", "", ... original ... )`:

```
  IF(TRIM(F19)="", "", 
    IF(COUNTIFS('SHARES LOG'!O:O,
                "L",
                'SHARES LOG'!B:B,
                ">="&DATE(2021,2,1),
                'SHARES LOG'!B:B,
                "<="&DATE(2021,2,28)), 
       COUNTIFS('SHARES LOG'!O:O,
                "L",
                'SHARES LOG'!B:B,
                ">="&DATE(2021,2,1),
                'SHARES LOG'!B:B,
                "<="&DATE(2021,2,28)), 
       "")
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have wrapped the formula as suggested however now getting the #NAME? error when there IS data entered into F19 (note G19 should now be conducting the COUNTIF when there is data in F19)

Comment: can you paste exactly what you have typed in to the cell please? `#name?` is because a function name can not be resolved, in this case it can only be `TRIM` - is your local language english? if not you may need to use the local equivalent of trim. if it is english then there may be a typo

Comment: I used : ```=IF(TRIM(F19)="", "",IF(COUNTIFS('SHARES LOG'!O:O,"L",'SHARES LOG'!B:B,">="&DATE(2021,2,1),'SHARES LOG'!B:B,"<="&DATE(2021,2,28)),COUNTIFS('SHARES LOG'!O:O,"L",'SHARES LOG'!B:B,">="&DATE(2021,2,1),'SHARES LOG'!B:B,"<="&DATE(2021,2,28)),””))``` and yes my local language is english

Comment: I have pasted that into my test sheet and i get no error.remove the trim and see if that makes any difference. Can you confirm your language also? thanks

Comment: Removing ```TRIM``` and using the following :  ```=IF(F19)="", "",IF(COUNTIFS('SHARES LOG'!O:O,"L",'SHARES LOG'!B:B,">="&DATE(2021,2,1),'SHARES LOG'!B:B,"<="&DATE(2021,2,28)),COUNTIFS('SHARES LOG'!O:O,"L",'SHARES LOG'!B:B,">="&DATE(2021,2,1),'SHARES LOG'!B:B,"<="&DATE(2021,2,28)),””))```still gives the ```#NAME?``` error. Language is english

Comment: That cant be in the cell because there is a syntax error here: `=IF(F19)=""` - you are missing an open bracket. Nonetheless, bizarre: a couple of things: 1. what is the value of `F19`? if that is `#name?` that error will be passed on to `g19` 2. change the end of the function from `””` to `""`

Comment: Fixed. I changed ”” to "" and added a 0 between the latter. Thanks again.